# Javascript full screen display issues

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to put a text particle effect on my website. I have tested it on Codepen and works great but does not work on my website.

The text shows but the effect does not work as required. The text stays in a static position on the screen but the hover effect is below the word.
taking the mose through the text does nothing, if I move the mouse to the bottom of the screen the effect works on the text above.

The text stays static, however, when I move scroll down, the position of the text effect stays at the bottom of the screen until it ends up below the `div` and stops working all together.

I was wondering if someone could help me centre this behind the text.

Also I am keen to change the colour of the text, to a linear gradient from `#125eaa` to `#d52027`

The link to the page on my site - https://www.supplementgenie.co.uk/testpage

link to my codepen - https://codepen.io/Paulmcf87/pen/gjpgOB

However, when I run this code on JS Fiddle it gives me a 404 error?

You will see, running code below it works great as on Codepen. It doesnt seem to translate properly to a full screen
Any help would be great

The code I am using

```js
var pixels=new Array();
    var canv=$('canv');
    var ctx=canv.getContext('2d');
    var wordCanv=$('wordCanv');
    var wordCtx=wordCanv.getContext('2d');
    var mx=-1;
    var my=-1;
    var words="";
    var txt=new Array();
    var cw=0;
    var ch=0;
    var resolution=1;
    var n=0;
    var timerRunning=false;
    var resHalfFloor=0;
    var resHalfCeil=0;
    function canv_mousemove(evt)
    {
      mx=evt.clientX-canv.offsetLeft;
      my=evt.clientY-canv.offsetTop;
    }
    function Pixel(homeX,homeY)
    {
      this.homeX=homeX;
      this.homeY=homeY;
      this.x=Math.random()*cw;
      this.y=Math.random()*ch;
      //tmp
      this.xVelocity=Math.random()*10-5;
      this.yVelocity=Math.random()*10-5;
    }
    Pixel.prototype.move=function()
    {
      var homeDX=this.homeX-this.x;
      var homeDY=this.homeY-this.y;
      var homeDistance=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(homeDX,2) + Math.pow(homeDY,2));
      var homeForce=homeDistance*0.01;
      var homeAngle=Math.atan2(homeDY,homeDX);
      var cursorForce=0;
      var cursorAngle=0;
      if(mx >= 0)
      {
        var cursorDX=this.x-mx;
        var cursorDY=this.y-my;
        var cursorDistanceSquared=Math.pow(cursorDX,2) + Math.pow(cursorDY,2);
        cursorForce=Math.min(10000/cursorDistanceSquared,10000);
        cursorAngle=Math.atan2(cursorDY,cursorDX);
      }
      else
      {
        cursorForce=0;
        cursorAngle=0;
      }
      this.xVelocity+=homeForce*Math.cos(homeAngle) + cursorForce*Math.cos(cursorAngle);
      this.yVelocity+=homeForce*Math.sin(homeAngle) + cursorForce*Math.sin(cursorAngle);
      this.xVelocity*=0.92;
      this.yVelocity*=0.92;
      this.x+=this.xVelocity;
      this.y+=this.yVelocity;
    }
    function $(id)
    {
      return document.getElementById(id);
    }
    function timer()
    {
      if(!timerRunning)
      {
        timerRunning=true;
        setTimeout(timer,33);
        for(var i=0;i<pixels.length;i++)
        {
          pixels[i].move();
        }
        drawPixels();
        wordsTxt.focus();
        n++;
        if(n%10==0 && (cw!=document.body.clientWidth || ch!=document.body.clientHeight)) body_resize();
        timerRunning=false;
      }
      else
      {
        setTimeout(timer,10);
      }
    }
    function getRandomColor(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }
    function drawPixels()
    {
      var imageData=ctx.createImageData(cw,ch);
      var actualData=imageData.data;
      var index;
      var goodX;
      var goodY;
      var realX;
      var realY;
      for(var i=0;i<pixels.length;i++)
      {
        goodX=Math.floor(pixels[i].x);
        goodY=Math.floor(pixels[i].y);
        for(realX=goodX-resHalfFloor; realX<=goodX+resHalfCeil && realX>=0 && realX<cw;realX++)
        {
          for(realY=goodY-resHalfFloor; realY<=goodY+resHalfCeil && realY>=0 && realY<ch;realY++)
          {
            index=(realY*imageData.width + realX)*4;
            actualData[index+3]=realX;
            actualData[index+2]=realX;
            actualData[index+1]=realY;
          }
        }
      }
      imageData.data=actualData;
      ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
    }
    function readWords()
    {
      words=$('wordsTxt').value;
      txt=words.split('\n');
    }
    function init()
    {
      readWords();
      var fontSize=200;
      var wordWidth=0;
      do
      {
        wordWidth=0;
        fontSize-=5;
        wordCtx.font=fontSize+"px Avenir, sans-serif";
        for(var i=0;i<txt.length;i++)
        {
          var w=wordCtx.measureText(txt[i]).width;
          if(w>wordWidth) wordWidth=w;
        }
      } while(wordWidth>cw-50 || fontSize*txt.length > ch-50)
      wordCtx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
      wordCtx.textAlign="center";
      wordCtx.textBaseline="middle";
      for(var i=0;i<txt.length;i++)
      {
        wordCtx.fillText(txt[i],cw/2,ch/2 - fontSize*(txt.length/2-(i+0.5)));
      }
      var index=0;
      var imageData=wordCtx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch);
      for(var x=0;x<imageData.width;x+=resolution) //var i=0;i<imageData.data.length;i+=4)
      {
        for(var y=0;y<imageData.height;y+=resolution)
        {
          i=(y*imageData.width + x)*4;
          if(imageData.data[i+3]>128)
          {
            if(index >= pixels.length)
            {
              pixels[index]=new Pixel(x,y);
            }
            else
            {
              pixels[index].homeX=x;
              pixels[index].homeY=y;
            }
            index++;
          }
        }
      }
      pixels.splice(index,pixels.length-index);
    }
    function body_resize()
    {
      cw=document.body.clientWidth;
      ch=document.body.clientHeight;
      canv.width=cw;
      canv.height=ch;
      wordCanv.width=cw;
      wordCanv.height=ch;
      init();
    }
    wordsTxt.focus();
    wordsTxt.value="Supplement Genie";
          resolution=1;
    resHalfFloor=Math.floor(resolution/2);
    resHalfCeil=Math.ceil(resolution/2);
    body_resize();
    timer();
```

```css
#wordsTxt{
    display:none
}
div.pixeltext canvas{
    width:98vw;
    height:100vh;
}
div.pixeltext{
    background-color: #d52027;
```

```html
 <div class="pixeltext">
 <canvas id="canv" onmousemove="canv_mousemove(event);" onmouseout="mx=-1;my=-1;">
    you need a canvas-enabled browser, such as Google Chrome
  </canvas>
  <canvas id="wordCanv" width="500px" height="500px" style="border:1px solid black;display:none;">
  </canvas>
<textarea id="wordsTxt" style="position:absolute;left:-100;top:-100;" onblur="init();" onkeyup="init();" onclick="init();"></textarea>
<div>
```

Comment: Your codepen will also not work if you change the CSS dimensions of the canvas (*for example to half*).

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli  thank you for your comment. I knew the codepen one wouldnt work if the dimensions were changed, I more had it there to show that it can work. My main issue is how to ammend it so that the issue does not exist and the effect trigger lies directly over/behind the image. have you any idea how to sort it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the `cw`,`ch` variables based on the canvas dimensions and not on the `document.body.clientWidth` etc.

Also you should avoid using `canv.offsetLeft` and `canv.offsetTop` since your element is inside other positioned elements and the `offset` properties return the position relative to the closest positioned ancestor.

Using `canv.getBoundingClientRect` which returns the `width`/`height` and `top`/`left`/`right`/`bottom` properties relative to the viewport will solve the problem.

(*your codepen was also using wrong names of the methods you had created*)

See https://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/rreagp which basically modifies the following methods

```js
function canvMousemove(evt) {
  var rect = canv.getBoundingClientRect();
  mx = evt.clientX - rect.left;
  my = evt.clientY - rect.top;
}

function body_resize() {
  var rect = canv.getBoundingClientRect()
  cw = rect.width;
  ch = rect.height;

  console.log(ch);
  canv.width = cw;
  canv.height = ch;
  wordCanv.width = cw;
  wordCanv.height = ch;

  init();
}
```

In your site i noticed a `timer` method which should also be modified to

```js
function timer() {
  var rect;
  if (!timerRunning) {
    timerRunning = true;
    setTimeout(timer, 33);
    for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
      pixels[i].move();
    }
    drawPixels();
    wordsTxt.focus();
    n++;

    rect = canv.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (n % 10 == 0 && (cw != rect.width || ch != rect.height)) body_resize();
    timerRunning = false;
  } else {
    setTimeout(timer, 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats been a massive help. I am new to Javascript and basically tried taking different pieces from similar effects that I have seen and piece them together to make a custom script. Without sounding like taking liberties. would you know how to change the colour gradient? Ive played about but got nowhere

Comment: @SupGen you would need to alter the `drawPixels` method and use the `actualData[index]`,`actualData[index+1]`,`actualData[index+2]`,`actualData[index+3]` which refer to RGBA (*red,green,blue,alpha*) and set them anyway you want depending on the `realX`, `realY` of the pixel.